# How to ensure Service is restarted before commands from Exec resource execute?

Tags: puppet

**(Update)** I left out an important line of code in my original question.

I am write a puppet module that will create local storage.  The un-automated way of does this is.

1. Edit the /etc/multipath.conf file
2. Restart the multipathd daemon
3. Execute pvcreate $device
4. Execute vgcreate $volume_name $device

So in my puppet module I want to make sure the multipathd daemon gets restarted if the /etc/multipath.conf file changes. So I wrote my puppet manifest this way.

```
Service['multipathd'] -> Anchor['create_storage_volume::begin']

...

file { '/etc/multipath.conf':
    ensure  => file,
    content => template( 'local_storage::hadoop/multipath.conf.erb' ),
    owner   => 'root',
    mode    => '0600',
    notify  => Service['multipathd'],
} -> 
service { 'multipathd':
    enable => true,
    ensure => running,
}

anchor { 'create_storage_volume::begin': } ->

exec { "pvcreate ${device}":
    path   => ['/usr/sbin', '/bin'],
    unless => "pvs | grep ${"volume_name},
} ->
exec { "vgcreate ${volume_name} ${device}":
    path   => ['/usr/sbin', '/bin'],
    unless => "pvs | grep ${"volume_name},
} -> # -> do nova config stuff
anchor { 'create_storage_volume::end': }

...
```

My question is, "does the above code guarantee that the multipathd daemon gets restarted before the pvcreate and vgcreate commands are executed"? Do I need to add more resource order with something like ...

```
 Service['multipathd'] -> Anchor['local_storage::begin']
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, "does the above code guarantee that the multipathd daemon gets restarted before the pvcreate and vgcreate commands are executed"?

No.  Both `Service['multipathd']` and `Exec["pvcreate ${device}"]` will be applied after `File['/etc/multipath.conf']`, but nothing in what you've presented the relative order of application of the Service and the Exec.

I'd probably write it like this, instead:

```
file { '/etc/multipath.conf':
    ensure  => file,
    content => template( 'local_storage::hadoop/multipath.conf.erb' ),
    owner   => 'root',
    mode    => '0600',
} ~>
Service['multipathd'] ->
exec { "pvcreate ${device}":
    path   => ['/usr/sbin', '/bin'],
    unless => "pvs | grep ${"volume_name},
} ->
# ...
```

Note the use of [the *notifying* chain operator](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_relationships.html#syntax-chaining-arrows); this is a less-used feature of the Puppet language.

---

With respect to the update to the question, the key requirement for the `Service` to be refreshed before the `Exec` is applied is that there be an ordering relationship between the two, whether direct or transitive.  In the modified question, the resources involved have such a relationship already.

The original answer does gloss over a fine point here, which I called out in comments: Puppet does not actually document explicitly when resource refreshes happen relative to anything else.  The documented semantics have some implications for that, but no firm rule is given.  In practice, through Puppet 4, if a resource refresh happens, it will happen immediately after that resource is synced -- or immediately after it would have been synced if it had needed to be.

Comment: Thank for you answer. I have a few questions.  I left out this line in my original question: Service['multipathd'] -> Anchor['create_storage_volume::begin'] (I'll update my questions) but does that ensure that the service, multipathd, will be restarted before my Exec resources execute?

Comment: Technically, Puppet's documentation says nothing explicit about the timing of resource refreshes.  In practice, in current and historical versions of Puppet, if a resource is going to refresh then it will do so immediately after it is (or would have been) synced.

Comment: @RedCricket My only additional suggestion here would be to check out Puppet's `lvm` module.